Removing the lightbox feature on Image Gallery in Get Response
Hello I'd appreciate some help!
I have this landing page made on GetResponse: https://jmc.hacktivatuvida.com/ and we want to remove the lightbox feature on the images is there any way we can achieve this with custom code?
example of the image in lightbox
I thinks this can give you an example of the code:
